# Javascript .replace() / regex with code as string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to "remove" (just replace it with "") the following String:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("img").src="http://www.google.com"
</script>
```

From the following String:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>
var PAswf = "_ADPATH_[%SWF File%]";
var advurl = "_ADCLICK_";
var PAadvurl = escape(advurl);
var PAwidth = "[%Width%]";
var PAheight = "[%Height%]";
var wmValue = "_ADDCP(wm)_";
if (!wmValue)wmValue = "opaque";
var PAwmode = wmValue;
document.write('<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"');
document.write(' WIDTH="'+ PAwidth +'" HEIGHT="'+ PAheight +'">');
document.write('<PARAM NAME=movie VAL'+'UE="' + PAswf + '?clickTag='+ PAadvurl +'"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high><PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE='+ PAwmode +'>');
document.write('<EMBED sr'+'c="'+PAswf + '?clickTag='+ PAadvurl +'" quality=high wmode='+ PAwmode);
document.write(' swLiveConnect=TRUE WIDTH="'+ PAwidth +'" HEIGHT="'+ PAheight +'"');
document.write(' TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash">');
document.write('</EMBED></OBJECT>');
</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("img").src="http://www.google.com"
</script>
```

As you can see, the String is at the bottom of the code block, but that shouldn't really matter. I've stored the first string as a variable, `codeString`, and tried the following.

```
// code refers to the bigger code string
code.replace(/codeString/gm, "");
```

Doesn't seem to match. I'm sure I'm doing something wildly wrong, but I've searched for about an hour and have come up empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you properly escaped your regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/codeString/` is a regular expression searching for the literal "codeString", not a variable containing a pattern. Also, `string.replace(pattern, replacement)` does not modify `string` but returns a new string with the replacement applied.

You do not need a regular expression for stripping fixed strings like this, the next code will remove the string once from `code`:

```
var codeString = '<script type="text/javascript">\n' +
    'document.createElement("img").src="http://www.google.com"\n' +
    '<\/script>';
code = code.replace(codeString, "");
```

Comment: **WARNING** write `'</script>'` as `'</sc'+'ript>'` when you haven't defined a Doctype, combined with `//<[CDATA[...//]]>`, or your script will end too early.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the replace() doesn't actually modify the string. Needed to be re-assigned and it worked. Silly! :)

Comment: @Rob Good point, using `<\/script>` now. Note that it does not matter if the code was contained in an external js file.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can start with

```
code.replace(codestring, "");
```

If it needs to be a regular expression, you can use:

```
code.replace(new RegExp(codestring, "gm"), "");
```

but be aware that the regex metacharacters should be escaped with backslashes.

Comment: In this particular case: `(`, `)` and `.` --> `\(`, `\)` and `\.`.